# why is this nav becoming unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page:

http://www.places4two.de/  if you go to "Login/Anmelden", you will come to login page. but the navigation becomes unclickable in this page. can someone help me to fix this? i am kinda lost

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.mainmenu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0px 50px 45px;
    z-index: 1000; /* it must be above 1000 */
    position: relative;
}
```

It should work

Comment: great! working like a charm. thanks a lot